# Search in Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a function to search an element in linked list in c, it works if the element exist, but I don't know how to write the code so that it returns "not found" if the element doesn't exist.
Here is the search function

```
void search(Node *head, int c)
{ 
    int count = 0;
    Node *temp3 = head;

    while (temp3 != NULL) {
        if (temp3->data != c) {
            count++;
            temp3 = temp3->next;
            printf("Element found at: %d \n", count);
        } else 
            printf("Element not found");
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what the function shall return.

Comment: Please explain further what exactly you want your program to do when 1. the element is found, and 2. when the element is not found. Do you want the function to continue running after printing an appropriate message or should it return in both cases, after printing the message? If you want the function to continue running after printing an appropriate message, should it run the same code in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just loop through the list and set a flag or count the occurrences when you find the element (in addition to printing its node number). Then you can just test the flag to print `"Element not found"` if that's the case:

```c
void search(Node *head, int c) { 
    int count = 0, found = 0;

    for (Node *temp3 = head; temp3 != NULL; temp3 = temp3->next) {
        count++;
        if (temp3->data == c) {
            found++;
            printf("Element found at: %d\n", count);
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        printf("Element not found\n");
    } 
}
```

Comment: It seems inefficient to continue the search once the element has been found. However, the OP did not clearly specify whether the desired element can be in the list more than once (at least one other answer makes the assumption that this is not the case), so I am also upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case your list can only contain one occurrence of the element, it would probably be more helpful to return it:

```c
Node *search(Node *head, int c)
{
    Node *n;

    for (n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next) {
        if(n->data == c)
            break;
    }
    
    return n;
}

// Somewhere else

Node *res = search(head, 123);

if (res != NULL) {
    // Do something
} else {
    puts("Element not found.");
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: In the second example, you could simply write `for (n = head; n != NULL && n->data != c; n = n->next) ; //empty statement` That way, the `if(n->data == c) break;` would not be necessary.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel why would I? It's semantically equivalent and it's only harder to understand.

Comment: Personally, I think my version is easier to understand, as the loop will run until either `n == NULL` or `n->data == c`. Therefore, I believe it makes sense to combine both loop conditions inside the `while` statement using the `&&` operator, instead of using a `break` statement inside the `while` block. However, I guess that is a matter of taste. I have upvoted your answer anyway.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel an empty for loop is never easier to understand IMHO, specially for a novice programmer. I guess that's a matter of taste ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

```
void search(Node* head, int c)
{ 
    int count = 0;
    Node* temp3 = head;

    while(temp3 != NULL )
    {
        if(temp3 -> data != c) {
            count ++;
            temp3 = temp3 -> next;
            printf("Element found at: %d \n", count);
            break;
        } 
    } 
    if(temp3 == NULL)
            printf("Element not found");

}
```

here you go

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution could be like this (-1 is interpreted as not found):

```
int search(Node* head, int c)
{ 
    int count = 0;
    Node* temp3 = head;

    while(temp3 != NULL )
    {
        if(temp3 -> data == c) {
            return count;
        } else(temp3 -> data != c) {
            ++count;
            temp3 = temp3 -> next;
        } 
    } 
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: please, add brief explaination of ur example